# How to generate a C array out of an image to be viewed on an eInk display?

Tags: display, imagemagick, image-editing

I'm trying to draw an image on a 480x280 2-color ePaper display from Waveshare.

I control the display using a RaspberryPi Pico.

First I make sure that the image is 480x280. Then I convert it to a byte array using **ImageMagick** using the following command:

```
convert icon.jpeg -colorspace Gray icon.h
```

This generates an array with **134415** entries. Although I expected (480x280 = **134400**). I don't know what is cause of this difference.

This array doesn't displayed correctly on the display. The displayed image has some relation with the original image but it's kind of compressed or mis-oriented and very small. I'm not really sure. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?!

Comment: I suggest you add images; use or smartphone if you have nothing else. As this is right now, nobody will be able to reply meaningfully.

Comment: FWIW 130k bytes for an icon seems oddly large, still you say it is small (default size for an icon?).

Comment: The extra bits (what you are labelling as "entries") are some sort of header. I'm searching for the actual format/specification of that header/the array myself which is why I ended up here. All I can say for sure is that in the array the header portions are terminated with 0x0A. If you leave those headers in the image data starting point/first color value and pitch will be misaligned which is why your image doesn't display correctly.

Also this is a question that belongs on StackOverflow, not SuperUser.